# Command Center media buttons is not syncing with App's media state Swift Unity

Tags: swift, unity-game-engine, avplayer, mpremotecommandcenter

I have created a media player plugin using `swift framework` for my `Unity` project, the media player works fine on the app.

But, when the App's media state is `paused` the Command Center media button does not update its still on the `pause icon` and same as with `playing` the button does not update.

I already have initiated the AVAudioSession shared instance and set the category to `.playback` and have also set the `.setActive` to `true`.

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession
                .sharedInstance()
            try audioSession
                .setCategory(
                    .playback,
                    mode: .default
                )
            print("Playback OK")
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
            print("Session is Active")
```

I also have initialised the `command center`, for handling the `play` and `pause` events whenever the buttons are clicked in command center.

```
self.commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
        self.commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [weak self] (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
            self?.play()
            return .success
        }
        
        // Add handler for Pause Command
        self.commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
        self.commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [weak self] (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
            self?.pause()
            return .success
        }
```

This is the code for the handling the `pause`

```
self.nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime())
            self.nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentItem!.duration);
            self.nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = 0
            self.nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyDefaultPlaybackRate] = 0
            
            MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = self.nowPlayingInfo
self.player.pause()
```

and This is the code for handling the `play`

```
self.nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime())
            self.nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentItem!.duration);
            self.nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = 1
            self.nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyDefaultPlaybackRate] = 1
            MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = self.nowPlayingInfo;
self.player.play()
```

What i am expecting is when i click on pause in the App the `command center's` button should be the `play icon`
if I click on play the `command center's` button should be `pause icon`, but right now nothing is working.